# chat.js doughnut chart font size not working

Tags: javascript, charts, donut-chart

I am using chart.js to drwa doughnut chart.I tried to change label font size with my below code but its not working for me.

also I tried to wrap it in two lines to show full label but wrap is also not working.

Attached is sample example of chart where United Arab emirates is Label which is cutting and not showing fully for me  /[image]

My code is :

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Fruits',
        data: ['one', 'two','three','three', 'four', 'five'],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
                    borderWidth: 1,

               fontSize:18,  // This is not working 
               wrap: true,   // This is not working 
               itemWrap: true,   // This is not working 


    }]
},
options: {

    legend: {
            display: false  ,

    },

}
});
```

Anyone if any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try to use this line

```
  // Global Options

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
     rest of your code..
 }
```

Comment: Did you manage to make  `wrap: true,   // This is not working 
               itemWrap: true,   // This is not working ` work?